# Geoserver labeling algorithm

Tags: geoserver, cartography, labeling, algorithm

I'm really interested in knowing what kind of algorithm does GeoServer use when presenting its maps.

GeoServer has its own algorithms, for instant the labelling algorithm. Is there a possibility to change it or modify the algorithm or add something to it? If so where can we find it? How we can change it if we want to?

I see that the algorithm is missing a few standards and it would be helpful if it could be modified.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to study the [renderer](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/renderer/Renderer2D.java) in GeoTools which calls the labeling subsystem (https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/renderer/label).

Before you go too far down that route feel free to write a [proposal](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/procedures/proposal.html) and discuss it on the [developers list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/geotools-devel).